# TabPane shrink to biggest child

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am breaking my head to make this work. Basically I have 2 Tabs. Initially one of them has content which let's suppose is 100px big (I don't know the sizes in advance. This is just an example) and the other has no content.
After some event, I add to the previously empty tab something with, let's say,a 200px height.

Up to hear all good. The TabPane resizes (after me calling requestLayout() ) correctly and fits the new content.

Now if I remove the 200px content, I would like the tab pane to go back to being 100px high, i.e. the biggest item still left on the tabs, however it remains at 200px leaving me with a lot of empty space. Could someone provide me a clue of how to solve this?

Here is my Demo code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabPaneTest extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Test 1");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Test 2");

        final Pane tab2Content = new Pane();
        tab2Content.getStyleClass().add("tab2Content");
        tab2.setContent(tab2Content);

        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);

        Button addSquare = new Button("Add");
        addSquare.setOnAction(event -> {
            final Pane tab1Content = new Pane();
            tab1Content.getStyleClass().add("tab1Content");

            tab1.setContent(tab1Content);

            tabPane.requestLayout();
        });

        Button removeSquare = new Button("Remove");
        removeSquare.setOnAction(event -> {
            tab1.setContent(null);
            tabPane.requestLayout();
        });
        HBox buttons = new HBox(addSquare, removeSquare);


        VBox vBox = new VBox(tabPane, buttons);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 500, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(LargeTooltipSample.class.getResource("tabPaneTest.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

and here is my CSS (just to better visualize the content):

```
.tab2Content{
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-max-height: 100;
    -fx-pref-height: 100;
    -fx-max-width: 100;
    -fx-pref-width: 100;
}

.tab1Content{
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-max-height: 200;
    -fx-pref-height: 200;
    -fx-max-width: 200;
    -fx-pref-width: 200;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Test 1");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Test 2");

        final Pane tab2Content = new Pane();
        final Pane tab1Content = new Pane();

        tab2Content.getStyleClass().add("tab2Content");
        tab2.setContent(tab2Content);

        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);

        Button addSquare = new Button("Add");
        Button removeSquare = new Button("Remove");
        HBox buttons = new HBox(addSquare, removeSquare);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(tabPane, buttons);


        double[] tabPaneOriginalHeight = new double[1];//Used to hold tabPane's original height.

        addSquare.setOnAction(event -> {  

        System.out.println(tabPane.getHeight());
        tab1Content.getStyleClass().add("tab1Content");
        tab1.setContent(tab1Content);    
        System.out.println(tabPane.getHeight());
        tabPane.setPrefHeight(200);//sets the height to 200 after adding tabl1 content
        tabPane.requestLayout();


    });


    removeSquare.setOnAction(event -> {
        System.out.println(tabPane.getHeight());

        tab1Content.getStyleClass().remove("tab1Content");
        tab1.setContent(tab1Content);
        System.out.println(tabPane.getHeight());
        tabPane.setPrefHeight(100);//sets the height to 100 after removing tab1 content
        tabPane.requestLayout(); 
    });




        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 500, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(JavaFXApplication16.class.getResource("tabPaneTest.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: Someone will have a better way by binding.

Comment: this does work for this example but imagine the following scenario:
The 200px part was in place already. And then you remove it leaving only the 100px one. It won't re-scale to 100px by using your method because the  "original height" was 200px and not 100px :(

Comment: Well instead of tabPane.setPrefHeight(tabPaneOriginalHeight[0]); try tabPane.setPrefHeight(100);

Comment: I tested it in Netbeans. It appears to be working fine. Does it meet your standard?

Comment: unfortunately not Sedrick. You are adapting the problem to the example given. I need to create something that can work more broadly, i.e. I don't know the size of the pixels that I want to revert to. Ideally I would just check each tab content and see the tallest item, but I don't know this before hand

Comment: You should rephrase your question and your example. I solved the questions as written.

Comment: very well I will do that... thanks for the suggestion